# How do I check UuidCreate() return values?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, uuid

MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `UuidCreate()` can return the following error codes:

- RPC_S_OK The call succeeded.
- RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY The UUID is guaranteed to be unique to this computer only.
- RPC_S_UUID_NO_ADDRESS Cannot get Ethernet or token-ring hardware address for this computer.

The first one is clear - it just worked. The second one - well, sort of worked and it will do for me. The third one is not clear at all - was it generated anyway or not?

Also it's unclear if other codes are possible.

How exactly do I check the return value of `UuidCreate()`? Which are good ones and which are not?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you only have to check for RPC_S_OK as UuidCreate() does not return the RPC_S_UUID_NO_ADDRESS error code, since Windows 2000 Professional (or Win2K3?). This is because UuidCreate() stopped using the network hardware address to generate the UUID. I have used this quite extensively and have never encountered a failed UuidCreate() situation so far.

There are some details at UuidCreateSequential docmentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

EDIT: I should rather say '... UuidCreate() should not return the RPC_S_UUID_NO_ADDRESS error code.' as I can't be factual about it.